# Intersection of ray and non-axis-aligned box

Tags: physics, mathematics, matrix, geometry, intersection

I need to compute the intersection of a ray with a non-axis aligned box. Currently, I transform the ray into the local space of the box, do classic ray-AABB intersection and transform the intersection back to world space. This requires 4 matrix multiplications (2 for the ray, 2 for the entry and exit points of the intersection).

I was wondering what could be a better approach to this problem. Most resource I could find focus on the AABB case.

Comment: Your current solution sounds pretty darn good. Have your profiled this and found that the matrix multiplications are the biggest bottleneck in your entire game? If so, you might get even better wins by using an acceleration structure to trim down the number of raycasts you need to actually perform, culling out ones that will definitely not hit and prioritizing the earliest hits.

Comment: I have very few boxes to ray cast against. Only one currently, and probably not more than maybe 4-8 in future. But I need to maintain high enough framerates for VR, so I'm trying to keep it as cheap as possible. Maybe I could do world space AABB checks to cull some rays earlier, before doing the more expensive matrix multiplications.

Comment: 4-8 raycasts worth of matrix multiplication will not be the determining factor in your VR framerate. Spend your energy optimizing your real bottlenecks and you will see much better performance gains.

Comment: I'm doing volume rendering, so I have one ray per pixel. That adds up quickly. But you're right, I should try to profile the bottlenecks.

Comment: Then you should be transforming your ray source into the box's space and firing your per-pixel rays against axis-aligned boxes, so you don't have this problem in the first place. Don't do something 1000 times that you can do once. (And of course, these should all be evaluated in parallel on the GPU, which won't break a sweat over 4-8 ray-box intersections per pixel)

Comment: @DMGregory Yes, that's exactly what I've been doing and it works great for one volume. However, I now want to render multiple volumes. I cannot do distance sorting, because the volumes can overlap. To have correct blending, I have to render all volumes in one go. For this I need to clamp the ray to start at the first intersection and end at the last one. This is why I want to figure out the intersections in world space. After that I can define the ray in each volume's space and do the normal ray marching, simply evaluating multiple volumes at each step. At least that's my current plan.